# Rails 4 Simple Admin to Update User Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having trouble getting my simple admin interface to work and was hoping you guys could open my eyes a bit.  I am guessing my @client variable is not quite fully working how I hoped.  It displays clients who have 'paid' on my 'generate' page but when I fill in the form_for and submit the database is not updated.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :generate]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :generate, :update]
  before_filter :setup_negative_captcha, :only => [:new, :create]
```

..

```
def generate
   @client = User.find_by! paid: 'true'
   if @client.update_attributes!(user_params)
    @client.comment = nil
    @client.paid = nil
    render 'generate'
   else
    flash[:error] = "Client not Saved"
    render 'generate'
  end
  end
```

...

```
 def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) or User.find_by! admin: 'true'
    end
```

...

```
<% if current_user.admin?  %>
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :hours1, value: "", rows:1 %><%= f.text_area :hours1_percent, value: "", rows:1 %><br>
<%= f.text_area :hours2, value: "", rows:1 %><%= f.text_area :hours2_percent, value: "", rows:1 %><br>
<%= f.submit " Generate Schedule" ,  class: 'btn-small btn-primary' %> 
<% end %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Signin", signin_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you show your logs? just the update query part.

Comment: Boom! Thanks rb.  I poked into what the log a bit more and realized I forgot to permit the parameters.  Thanks I will not make the same stupid mistake again.

Comment: Cool, you might wanna post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line `@client = User.find_by! paid: 'true'` returns a list of objects not one. Therefore, the next line won't work with you `if @client.update_attributes!(user_params)`. To solve, you have to assign `@client` one object not list of objects like: `@client = User.find(params[:id])` then in next line change to: `if @client.paid? && @client.update_attributes!(user_params)`

Comment: Forgot to Permit the Parameters!